# Class 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I had installed PragmaRx\Tracker package several months ago into my project.
I started to deleting the package from laravel project through following steps:

```
1. composer remove vendor/PragmaRx/Tracker
2. remove package name form composer.json file
3. removing package from provider and aliases list in config/app.php file
4. composer dump-autoload
5. composer update
6. also php artisan dump-autoload
```

I also tried a bunch of other ways to remove the package.

after removing the package I'm getting this error when I run any artisan command (even "php artisan serve" command):

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
      Class 'PragmaRX\Tracker\Vendor\Laravel\ServiceProvider' not found
```

It's obvious that the package and its related files have been removed! but I couldn't find out the error's reason.

my laravel version is 5.5.4 .

any idea?

Comment: What does that line in `ProviderRepository.php` contain?

Comment: It's a typical error for class not found error in laravel. check the file content in laravel project vandor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/foundation/ProviderRepository for more information! @NicoHaase

Answer (score 6, accepted):

finally I found the error's reason.It's because of laravel cache!!

in one hand I couldn't run any artisan command including "php artisan config:cache" to clear laravel cache, in the other hand the cache was the error's reason.So at first I re-installed the pachage :

```
composer require PragmaRx/Tracker
```

then :

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and finally :

```
composer remove PragmaRx/Tracker
```

Done.